# How to unzip and rename file based on position of filename in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a use case where I need to remove the last few numbers in the filename. How do I achieve this in Python?

```
Zip file: xyz_abc.gz
Unzipped version: xyz_abc_20180825_201808284520842.gz
Final Expected Filename: xyz_abc_20180825.gz
```

This has to be recursive since I have many files under the folder.

Comment: Hey there, what have you tried so far ? If there is a clear pattern the you can use python's regex  [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If the number is always the last part and is always after _ then you can use something like `name = '_'.join(filename.split('_')[:-1])` on the name without the extension ('.gz')

Answer (score -2):

To unzip you can the library 'zipfile'.